# Tweepy getting full tweet text

Tags: twitter, text

I am using the following code to retrieve the tweets using Tweepy API:

```
    try:
        text="retweeted: "+json_reply['retweeted_status']['text']
        user_name ="retweeted: "+json_reply['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name']
    except:
        text=json_reply['text']
        user_name=json_reply['user']['screen_name']
```

I am getting the following output tweets which do not match my expectations.

1) retweeted: M67 | Open Cluster in Cancer One of the oldest clusters in the Milky Way Often overlooked because of its neighbor M… [url here]

2) There may be a flurry of activity in your life today  even if ... More for Cancer [url here]

My expectation is that both these should not contain the elipsis. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

There is now an extended mode in the Twitter API to handle this case.

For instance, with tweepy (Python), you can get the full text using `tweet_mode='extended'` (not documented in the Tweepy doc). For instance:

```
print api.get_status('862328512405004288')._json['text']
```

> @tousuncotefoot @equipedefrance @CreditAgricole @AntoGriezmann @KMbappe @layvinkurzawa @UmtitiSam J'ai jamais vue d… https://tco/kALZ2ki9Vc

```
print api.get_status('862328512405004288', tweet_mode='extended')._json['full_text']
```

> @tousuncotefoot @equipedefrance @CreditAgricole @AntoGriezmann @KMbappe @layvinkurzawa @UmtitiSam J'ai jamais vue de match de foot et cela ferait un beau cadeau pour mon copain !!